# How to get ModelMetadata outside a view context?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to export some kind of data (build a file), so the data won't be produced (renderized) by Views but by pure C# code, ouside a view. But I need some ModelMetadata informations.

I ask also how to build a ModelMetadata inside unit tests, so also, outside Views ?

Comment: Create your domain model and manipulate it via your controller. I'm not sure what you're asking can you try to be more clear?

Comment: The answer from Darin (below) is very near what I need, but I cannot call FromLambdaExpression() compiled by "generic param" for a specific type. I can only determine the type in runtime (dynamically).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming you have a view model with some metadata:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Bar")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

you could retrieve this metadata like this:

```
ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<MyViewModel, string>(
    x => x.Foo, 
    new ViewDataDictionary<MyViewModel>()
);

Assert.AreEqual("Bar", metadata.DisplayName);
```

---

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments section here's how to obtain the metadata if only the type is known at runtime:

```
var type = typeof(MyViewModel);
var metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, type);
```

and if you want to get the metadata for a child property just specify the name of the property:

```
var type = typeof(MyViewModel);
var metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(null, type, "Foo");
```

Comment: unfortunately I can only determine the type in runtime. Is a way to call FromLambdaExpression() having only a Type class, maybe building an Expression manually ?